# How can i export app file in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Do you know how to export app file in Xcode?
(like .apk file in android)
I want to send my testing app to someone for feedback.
i have never tried it before. please let me know easy way to export app file.
(not all project, only a file which can be played in another iPhone)

Comment: Google for *Testflight* and *Ad-hoc deployment*.

Comment: for that you need to create certificate for export the app and for creating the certificate you need apple developer account.

Comment: Buy mac to start developing, buy iPhone to test it on real devices and now it seems that you can't even export your app without a payed developer account every year. That's true evil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First Archive it (**XCode->Product->Archive**).
  (For Archive button to be in visible state : either your device should be selected or generic ios device should be selected, incase any simulator is selected archive button will be disabled.)
- A Window will appear : 
  **Choose Export->AdHoc**.
- .ipa will be generated.
- u can use https://www.diawi.com/ for uploading and send app to anyone.

Comment: thank you for your comment. but how can i enable choose Export button?  enroll development id??

Comment: Yes,you have to enroll for developer program in case u didn't have one. Only then you can send your app file to anyone.

Comment: In xCode 12, choose distribute instead of export.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a very late response to this old question in case anyone else finds their way here and infers that it isn't possible to export an app to your own iPhone or iPad without a developer account. That isn't true. I unearthed these posts  when looking for an answer to the same question, and initially read them that way.

If you want to test an app you have written in XCode on your own iOS device you *do not* need a developer account. Provided the device you wish to test it on (or share it with) is physically nearby so that you can connect it to your macOS device to *pair with it* as a trusted device, it will remain paired when physically disconnected and accessible over a shared network by WiFi. You can build and run apps from XCode on to the iOS *destination device* and they will remain in place there and executable afterwards. There is a limit to how many exported apps there can be at one time, which seems to be 3.

Apple explain how to do all this [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running_your_app_in_the_simulator_or_on_a_device). You do need to have a registered App Store account, but that's the same one you use to buy apps and build projects in XCode, and it's free unless you want to distribute your app through the App Store.